# A rare property of Hausdorff spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Is there a Hausdorff topological space $X$ such  that for any continuous map $f: X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the set $f^{-1}(x)$ is either empty or infinite?

Comment: What happened to your other question, concerning spaces $X$ for which there is a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that is discontinuous at every point? I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I suppose it is this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247146/on-everywhere-discontinuous-functions (I do not have sufficient reputation to see deleted posts. But at the moment the question can be still seen in [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mathoverflow.net/questions/247146/on-everywhere-discontinuous-functions).)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, there is such a space. Let $X=2^{\omega_1}$ be the space of
binary sequences of length $\omega_1$, in the order topology
generated by the lexical order. So $X$ consists of the branches
through the tree $2^{<\omega_1}$, with the left-to-right order on
branches. This is an order topology of a linear order and hence
Hausdorff.

The key thing to notice is that every element $a\in X$ is the limit
of an $\omega_1$-sequence. If $a_\alpha\to a$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ and
$f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, it follows that $f(a_\alpha)\to
f(a)$. Since every convergent $\omega_1$-sequence in the reals is eventually constant, it must be that $f(a_\alpha)=f(a)$ for all
sufficiently large countable ordinals $\alpha$. So this space has
your desired property.

In fact, I claim that for every continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and every $a\in X$, the function is constant on an interval about $a$. To see this, we may find open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ so that $\{f(a)\}=\bigcap_n I_n$, and then $f$ is constant on $\bigcap_n f^{-1}I_n$. Each such $f^{-1}I_n$ is an open set containing $a$, and since there are only countably many, we may find an interval containing $a$ inside all of them.

Thus, this space has the property that every continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is locally constant, and every nonempty open set has size $2^{\omega_1}$.

Comment: One could argue similarly with the surreal line (or the surreal line at some birthday of uncountable cofinality, to make it a set), which also has the property that every continuous function to the reals is locally constant, for essentially similar reasons.

Comment: For the record, the completely regular spaces $X$ where every function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are locally constant are known as $P$-spaces. Equivalently, a $P$-space is a regular space where the countable intersection of open sets is open.

Answer (score 29):

How about this example: $[0,1]^A$ with the product topology, where $A$ is uncountable.  Then every nonempty $G_\delta$ set is uncountable.  Since your sets $f^{-1}(x)$ are $G_\delta$ sets, this has your property.

Comment: Nice example, Gerald.  It is similar to my example, but do you get the locally-constant property? It seems not, since the projection functions to the unit interval are continuous, but not locally constant. But if you used $2^A$ instead of $[0,1]^A$, then at least the projection functions would be locally constant. Is every continuous function locally constant in this case?

Comment: Locally constant in $\{0,1\}^A$?  No.  Think of the projection onto $\{0,1\}^B$, where $B \subset A$ is countable.  (In fact, the general continuous real-valued function factors through such a projection.) But we do have each nonempty level set $f^{-1}(x)$ has the same power as the whole space.

Comment: not so rare, huh?

Answer (score 3):

If $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a regular space, then the $P$-space coreflection of $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is the space generated by the basis $\{\bigcap_{n\in\omega}U_{n}\mid\forall n\,U_{n}\in\mathcal{S}\}$. A completely regular space $X$ satisfies the property that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is empty or infinite for any real $x$ if and only if the $P$-space coreflection of $X$ has no isolated points.

There exists infinite regular spaces $X$ where [every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is constant](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~freiwald/4181RegnotCReg.pdf) and in such spaces $f^{-1}(x)$ is always empty or infinite.